# Whats the best way to search files in a directory for multiple extensions and get the last write time according to filename

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file-extension

I am having a hard time mixing types with linq in the forloop. Basically i need to search a directory with a dbname, not knowing if the file will be .bak or .7z. If there are multiple files with the same dbname i need to get the one with extention .7z. If there are multiple files with same dbname and extention .7z I need to get the file with the last write time. This is what i have so far.

```
        string [] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var fileName in files)
        {
            var dbName = "Test";
            var extention7 = ".7z";
            var extentionBak = ".bak";
            if (fileName.Contains(dbName) && (fileName.Contains(extention7) || fileName.Contains(extentionBak)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName);
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't create a LINQ only solution for this - it will be too hard to understand.

Here is what I would do:

```
string GetDatabaseFile(string folder, string dbName)
{
    var files =
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, dbName + "*.*")
                 .Select(x => new { Path = x, Extension = Path.GetExtension(x) })
                 .Where(x => x.Extension == ".7z" || x.Extension == ".bak")
                 .ToArray();

    if(files.Length == 0)
        return null;
    if(files.Length == 1)
        return files[0].Path;
    var zippedFiles = files.Where(x => x.Extension == ".7z").ToArray();
    if(zippedFiles.Length == 1)
        return zippedFiles[0].Path;
    return zippedFiles.OrderByDescending(x => File.GetLastWriteTime(x.Path))
                      .First().Path;
}
```

Please note that this doesn't take into account the case where there are no .7z files but multiple .bak files for a DB. If this scenario can occur, you need to extend the method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Get files in directory:**

```
    var sourceFilePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory).Where(f =>  Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower() == ".exe" || 
                                                                                Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower() == ".dll" ||
                                                                                Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower() == ".config");
```

.
.
.

**File compare:**

```
    var sourceFileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    var destinationFileInfo = new FileInfo(destinationFilePath);

    var isNewer = sourceFileInfo.LastWriteTime.CompareTo(destinationFileInfo.LastWriteTime) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of packing everything in one if condition you should handle all cases separate:

```
var dbName = "Test";
var extention7 = ".7z";
var extentionBak = ".bak";
foreach (var fileName in files)
{
    if (!fileName.Contains(dbName)) continue; // wrong base name
    if (File.GetExtension(filename) == extention7)
    {
         // handle this case:
         // extract file date
         // remember latest file
    }
    else if(File.GetExtension(filename) == extentionBak)
    {
            // handle this case
    }
}
```